# What part of speech does the phrase act as: "of boiled cabbage and old rag mats" in "The hallway smelt of boiled cabbage and old rag mats"?

Tags: grammar

I am learning grammar and have decided to perform an exercise of analyzing Orwell's writings. I have stuck on a sentence from 1984:

> The hallway smelt of boiled cabbage and old rag mats.

I cannot identify a part of speech and a function of the phrase "of boiled cabbage and old rag mats."

The verb [smelt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smell) in the sense of "to have an odor or scent" is intransitive. Therefore the phrase is not an object.

The verb "*smelt*" is not *linking* because it does not express a state of being and cannot be replaced with "*is*." So the phrase is not a subjective complement.

The phrase may *describe* the verb "smelt" by providing information about specific odors. So it may be an *adverb*. I hesitate to identify it as an adverb because I cannot find a corresponding rule and example in grammar books.

What is the actual function of the phrase?

Comment: "Of boiled cabbage and old rag mats" is a **preposition phrase** headed by the prep "of". Its function is **complement** of the verb "smelt".

Comment: Thank you, BillJ. I have just started learning grammar, and your help is valuable. Some clarity saves me from struggling with doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The hallway smelt* [*of boiled cabbage and old rag mats*].

"Of boiled cabbage and old rag mats" is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "of". Its function is complement of the verb "smelt".

It qualifies as a complement rather than an adjunct (adverbial) because it is licensed by the head "smelt".